# how can I detect page when I compile all javascript to one file

Tags: javascript

I compile all my javascript for different pages into one file, so I have to identify page for my all.js. I can put a hidden element in my pages and let javascript detect this element, but I don't like this solution, are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: First question - why does your JS need to know what page it is on? It seems to me as somewhat questionable design. Is there perhaps a way to avoid it? (but then again - may be it's just me and you can go on and use the below answer)

Comment: I would agree with @ZenMaster, there has to be a better way to do this, if the pages are dynamic then, you can predefine the script needed easily while you are coding. Can you tell us a little scenario also.

Comment: I don't use any embed, so I need to know what page it is on. You means I define functions in all.js, and call it on pages. but I compile all page embed script to all.js

Answer (score 3):

You could go by the url using `location.href` (or another field from the `location` object).

However, a better approach is using a `data-` attribute on the body tag, e.g. `<body data-page="whatever">` and then using `$('body').data('page')` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 3):

If you script is based on pages, then compiling them into one script is a bad idea, load the file separately, it will be lighter and definately increase some performace.

Comment: Not necessarily - by having separate scripts the first load of *each* page is slower since another script needs to be loaded instead of just one script that is in the cache after the first load of *any* page.

Comment: @ThiefMaster you are right in a way, but loading a 100kb file, for lets say `$(function() { $("div").load("mytitle.php"); });,` does sound pretty bad, doesn't it? Even if it is cached.

Comment: When compiling javascripts into a single file you are likely to combine jQuery, various plugins and your custom scripts in the same file - and then those few bytes don't make any difference; actually, the HTTP request necessary to load it separately is much larger than the actual script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why do you need this, but in general it is not good practice to change dynamicaly change content of javascript file, since you are disabling javascript cacheing, what can be performance issue later.

Any way, you can solve it from other side, what about using all.js just to detect the page, where are you and then you can use this information, to load right javascript file dynamicaly, like in the following example

```
document.write('<script src="'+location.pathname+'.js"></script>');
```

Which will load same file as you are on, just with .js extension. So for example on index.html page it will load index.html.js file

Answer (score 0):

I almost always use MVC frameworks and tend to put my action and controller as classes on the body element

```
<body class="main_controller index">
```

Which lets you do things like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Only for lessons#search
    if (!$(body).hasClass('lessons search')) {
        return;
    }

    function close_style_filter_box() {
        $('#style_filter_box').slideUp();
    }

});


$(document).ready(function(){

    //Only for main_controller#index
    if (!$(body).hasClass('main_controller index')) {
        return;
    }

    function do_something_else_on_this_age() {
       ....
    }

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way is using javascript variable:

```
var PAGE = 'page1';
```

Comment: I am going to go and -1 this one. Sorry. For 2 reasons. One - it pollutes the global namespace. Second - if he has this in every JS file - they will collide and override each other.

Comment: -1 - This will not solve anything, where do you want this to be added? There is on all.js file, and when you will add this there, all pages will be defined as page1

Comment: @TranDinhThoai in that case - my first point still stands, but there is now a differen second point - that data is already accessible from JS in the way ThiefMaster explained.